# Best way to display big data

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, formatting

I would like to display this data, callable at any time, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice to do so.

```
countries = [
   dict(Name = "China", Population = "1,363,560,000"),
   dict(Name = "India", Population = "1,242,070,000"),
   dict(Name = "United States", Population = "317,768,000"),
   dict(Name = "Indonesia", Population = "249,866,000"),
   dict(Name = "Brazil", Population = "201,032,714"),
   dict(Name = "Pakistan", Population = "186,015,000"),
   dict(Name = "Nigeria", Population = "173,615,000"),
   dict(Name = "Bangladesh", Population = "152,518,015"),
   dict(Name = "Russia", Population = "143,700,000"),
   dict(Name = "Japan", Population = "127,120,000"),
   dict(Name = "Mexico", Population = "119,713,203"),
   dict(Name = "Philippines", Population = "99,329,000"),
   dict(Name = "Vietnam", Population = "89,708,900"),
   dict(Name = "Egypt", Population = "86,188,600"),
   dict(Name = "Germany", Population = "80,716,000"),
   dict(Name = "Iran", Population = "77,315,000"),
   dict(Name = "Turkey", Population = "76,667,864"),
   dict(Name = "Thailand", Population = "65,926,261"),
   dict(Name = "France", Population = "65,844,000"),
   dict(Name = "United Kingdom", Population = "63,705,000"),
   dict(Name = "Italy", Population = "59,996,777"),
   dict(Name = "South Africa", Population = "52,981,991"),
   dict(Name = "South Korea", Population = "50,219,669"),
   dict(Name = "Colombia", Population = "47,522,000"),
   dict(Name = "Spain", Population = "46,609,700"),
   dict(Name = "Ukraine", Population = "45,410,071"),
   dict(Name = "Kenya", Population = "44,354,000"),
   dict(Name = "Argentina", Population = "40,117,096"),
   dict(Name = "Poland", Population = "38,502,396"),
   dict(Name = "Sudan", Population = "37,964,000"),
   dict(Name = "Uganda", Population = "35,357,000"),
   dict(Name = "Canada", Population = "35,344,962"),
   dict(Name = "Iraq", Population = "34,035,000"),
   ]

print countries
```

Comment: And what, exactly, does this question have to do with code review? **Nothing!** Is our new policy that anything goes as long as it is easy to answer and tangentially includes the words 'best practice'?  This code does not display the data; the question is clearly about how solve the problem, not how to improve the existing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To format the data nicely for printing you can use the `ljust` method:

```
print "Country".ljust(15),"Population"
for country in countries:
    print country["Name"].ljust(15), country["Population"]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'll eventually have my game on here I'm building with this for review.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the data structure you have (a list of dicts), whose entries are already sorted in descending order of population, it appears that you want the output as a table.

The country name should probably be left justified.  The population, being numeric, should probably be right justified.  You'll have to decide on some arbitrary column widths.

Python has built in [formatting capability](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to accomplish this, with the ability to extract fields out of a dictionary.

You could define a function that is callable from anywhere.

```
def print_countries(countries):
    for c in countries:
        print "%(Name)-16s%(Population)16s" % (c)
```

For flexibility, you could define a stringifying function instead of a printing function.

```
def countries_to_str(countries):
    return "\n".join(["%(Name)-16s%(Population)16s" % (c) for c in countries])
```

Then you have the flexibility to output the result of `countries_to_str(countries)` anywhere you want, such as a file.